# Ask the compiler to optimize function for certain argument values

Tags: c++

I have a function with multiple arguments:

```
void foo(char* out, int a, int b, int c) {...}
```

This `foo` function contains a hot loop which runs 1-2 orders of magnitude faster when the compiler can optimize it by knowing `a`, `b` and `c`.
I do know the domain of `a`, `b` and `c`:

- `a` ∈ [0; 4)
- `b` ∈ [0; 8)
- `c` ∈ [0; 5)

I would like the compiler to generate 4 * 8 * 5 = 160 versions of `foo`, generate a jump table and jump to the right implementation based on the arguments. I need to keep the API of the function (take function args and not template params), but I can change the implementation and add helper functions.

One idea I had was creating a helper function with `A`, `B`, `C` template parameters and creating a 3D array of function pointers. However, I did not find a way to traverse the domain at compile time and generate each specialization.

Comment: This sounds almost like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Can you elaborate on what your loop is doing or share some more code? Have you considered profile guided optimizations?

Comment: The loop contains various loops and branches (say loop `i` from 0..`b` and check if `a` is divisible by `i`, if yes, add `c` to `*out` and increment `out`). The exact logic would be complicated to explain but is in a similar vein. When `a`, `b`, `c` are known by the compiler, it can generate branch-free code. The goal would be to eliminate the branches and generate one branchless version for each possible value of `{a, b, c}`. I did some measurements and the branch-free version is 20-30x faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your array of function pointers like this:

```
template <int A, int B, int C>
consteval std::array<std::array<std::array<void (*)(char*), C>, B>, A>
make_foo_array()
{
    std::array<std::array<std::array<void (*)(char*), C>, B>, A> res{};
    [&]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>){
        ([&]<std::size_t... Js>(auto I, std::index_sequence<Js...>){
            ([&]<std::size_t... Ks>(auto J, std::index_sequence<Ks...>){
                ((res[I()][J()][Ks] = &foo<I(), J(), Ks>), ...);
            }(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Js>(), std::make_index_sequence<C>()), ...);
        }(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Is>(), std::make_index_sequence<B>()), ...);
    }(std::make_index_sequence<A>());
    return res;
}

void foo(char* out, int a, int b, int c) {
    constexpr auto foos = make_foo_array<4, 8, 5>();

    foos[a][b][c](out);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MavKn81MG)

Comment: making it `static constexpr auto foos` produces less assembly, does this mean it is doing extra work than just a jump without `static` ?

Comment: It has to reinitialize the array into the heap every function call without static. With static, it is initialized once in the program life. Also, make it const to make the intent clear.

Comment: seems to depend on the compiler, clang does the right thing regardless of `static` while both gcc and msvc make 160 `mov` instructions without `static`, but they all agree it should be just a jump when you add `static`

Answer (score 1):

Since there are only three dimensions, you can generate every combination with partial functions:

```
template <int a, int b, int c>
void foo_templated(char *out) {
    printf("%d %d %d", a, b, c);
}

template <int a, int b>
void foo_c(char *out, int c) {
    switch (c) {
        case 0: return foo_templated<a,b,0>(out);
        case 1: return foo_templated<a,b,1>(out);
        case 2: return foo_templated<a,b,2>(out);
        case 3: return foo_templated<a,b,3>(out);
        case 4: return foo_templated<a,b,4>(out);
    }
}

template <int a>
void foo_bc(char *out, int b, int c) {
    switch (b) {
        case 0: return foo_c<a,0>(out, c);
        case 1: return foo_c<a,1>(out, c);
        case 2: return foo_c<a,2>(out, c);
        case 3: return foo_c<a,3>(out, c);
        case 4: return foo_c<a,4>(out, c);
        case 5: return foo_c<a,5>(out, c);
        case 6: return foo_c<a,6>(out, c);
        case 7: return foo_c<a,7>(out, c);
    }
}


void foo(char* out, int a, int b, int c) {
    switch (a) {
        case 0: return foo_bc<0>(out, b,c);
        case 1: return foo_bc<1>(out, b,c);
        case 2: return foo_bc<2>(out, b,c);
        case 3: return foo_bc<3>(out, b,c);
    }
}
```

This generates three dispatches instead of one, however.

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense. I wonder, is there a way to achieve the same with less boilerplate? And as you noted, the compiler does generate more than 1 jump (I hoped that it would be able to optimize it into a single lookup table but it was not).

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```cpp
namespace Foo {
    template <int a, int b, int c> void compiledFoo(char* out) {...}
    typedef void (*FooPtr)(char*);
    FooPtr compiledFoos[4][8][5];
    bool filled = false;
    void fill() {
        for (byte i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            for (byte j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                for (byte k = 0; k < 5; k++)
                    array[i][j][k] = compiledFoo<i, j, k>;
        filled = true;
    }
}

void foo(char *out, int a, int b, int c) {
    if (!Foo::filled) Foo::fill();
    return Foo::CompiledFoos[a][b][c](out);
}
```

This will create all required `compiledFoo`s.

Comment: Or you can write a switch by hand.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI but we want compiler optimization, we don't change the C++.

Comment: I was not clear and now updated the question. I'd like to keep the API of foo because callers won't know a, b, c at compile-time (we only know their domain but a, b and c are not constexpr). So the callers will need to pass them as function args and not template params. However, I can create helper functions for example and dispatch the call to those helper functions.

Comment: @DavidFrank maybe have a `compiledFoo` with the template params, add an optional bool arg to `foo` that defaults to false, and pass true to trigger `foo` to use `compiledFoo` behind the scenes.

Comment: @DavidFrank Oh, now I see. You could generate the 3D pointer array using templates and access as you said. Don't forget bound-checking, though.

Comment: I didn't find a way to generate the 3D pointer array using templates

Comment: Try this: `typedef void (*FooPtr)(char*)` `FooPtr array[4][8][5];` `for (byte i = 0; i < 4; i++) for (byte j = 0; j < 8; j++) for (byte k = 0; k < 5; k++) array[i][j][k] = compiledFoo<i, j, k>;`

Comment: @DavidFrank Function pointers may defeat optimization to some extent. My first choice would be a switch. Yes you will need 160 cases. Not ideal, but not a huge deal either. You can generate it with some macros if you are so inclined. Or you can write a template, but it might end up larger than a manually written switch. For 10,000 cases definitely write a template though. I will try to give an example shortly.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI What about three switches with 4, 8, and 5 cases respectively?

Comment: @MJTech Yes it s possible to nest the switches. You will need a couple of helper templates though. Could be even simpler than one big flat switch.

Comment: On the second though, if you don't absolutely need `foo` to be inlined, then an array of function pointers is perfectly fine.